# Why does not changing changing LC_ALL from utf to C speed up my grep?

Tags: grep, environment-variables

I wanted to try to speed up my already fast grep. I read that changing lc_all from utf to c was supposed to do this. However, it gives no speedup. What might the reasons be? How do I "debug" this?

Might caching of the file be the reason (do not have sudo access so can't clear the file from memory)?

Comment: Depends on your regexp. For some simple regexp (like `grep foo`), grep won't need to parse UTF-8, so will behave the same with LC_ALL=C

Comment: What environment variable did you set exactly? It's `LC_ALL`, not `lc_all`. Environment variables are case-sensitive. What is the output of `locale` before and after setting the environment variable(s) that you changed?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas That might be it. I search for a simple "^chr1\b".

Comment: @Gilles I used LC_ALL. I forgot to write it properly in the Q. Sorry.